# Problems with ContextLoaderListener

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I am working through a tutorial that uses Spring along with Apache Camel but I am having some issues with the spring configuration. I keep getting an error surrounding the ContextLoaderListener but I am not sure what the problem is. I have done simple Spring applications before and I believe that I have the web.xml layed out correctly but I am not an expert by any means.

If anyone knows a way to fix this error so I could actually run my project that would be extremely helpful, I have a copy of my web.xml and the error/stack below. Thank you!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app version="2.4"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" >

  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

  <!-- the listener that kick-starts Spring -->
 <listener>
    <listener-class>
      org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

 <!-- location of spring xml files -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:camel-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation1</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:cxf-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- CXF servlet -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<!-- all our webservices are mapped under this URI pattern -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/webservices/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

```
Could not instantiate listener org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListender
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListender
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:392)
    at runjettyrun.ProjectClassLoader.loadClass(ProjectClassLoader.java:89)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.loadClass(ContextHandler.java:1102)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.initListener(WebXmlConfiguration.java:630)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.initWebXmlElement(WebXmlConfiguration.java:368)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.initialize(WebXmlConfiguration.java:289)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.configure(WebXmlConfiguration.java:222)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.configureWebApp(WebXmlConfiguration.java:180)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1279)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:518)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:499)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at runjettyrun.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:97)
2013-01-16 01:45:03.468:WARN::failed CXFServlet: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/context/WebApplicationContext
2013-01-16 01:45:03.468:WARN::failed org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext@2aa49512{/camel-example-reportincident,C:\Users\patrick.archambeau\workspace\ApacheCamelTesting\camel-example-reportincident\src\main\webapp}: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/context/WebApplicationContext
2013-01-16 01:45:03.468:WARN::Error starting handlers
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/context/WebApplicationContext
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2404)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2714)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:343)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.newInstance(Holder.java:153)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:428)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:263)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:736)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1282)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:518)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:499)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at runjettyrun.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:97)
```

Comment: make sure you have added the spring-web dependency.

Comment: Yes I am using maven and I have the spring dependencies loaded, that is why I am extremely confused as to why this is happening

Answer (score 4):

The `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/context/WebApplicationContext` tells you that you're missing the WebApplicationContext class in your classpath. This class is found in spring-web.jar. So to fix this add spring-web to your classpath.

Comment: Right on.  I had the same error and it seems to recognize this class now.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following link
http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?60812-ClassNotFoundException-org.springframework.web.con-text.ContextLoaderListener

It says you can fix this problem by going to project properties -> Deployment Assembly and adding the Maven Dependency Build Path entry